# Detect Table Changes In A Database Without Modifications

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database ("DatabaseA") that I *cannot modify in any way*, but I need to detect the addition of rows to a table in it and then add a log record to a table in a separate database ("DatabaseB") along with some info about the user who added the row to DatabaseA.  (So it needs to be event-driven, not merely a periodic scan of the DatabaseA table.)

I know that normally, I could add a trigger to DatabaseA and run, say, a stored procedure to add log records to the DatabaseB table. But how can I do this *without modifying DatabaseA*?

I have free-reign to do whatever I like in DatabaseB.

**EDIT** in response to questions/comments ...

Databases A and B are MS SQL 2008/R2 databases (as tagged), users are interacting with the DB via a proprietary Windows desktop application (not my own) and each user has a SQL login associated with their application session.

Any ideas?

Comment: What database server are you using (MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres, etc)? Are users signing interacting with the database directly, or are they going through an application?

Comment: @JRLambert I updated the question with these details. Thanks.

Comment: Do the users all have their own database credentials? Or does the application have the credentials?

Comment: Always specify the version of software you are using. different versions have different features.

Comment: So do you know all the sproc names that can insert to the table you wish to monitor?

Comment: @dfundako No, and there is no guarantee that a stored procedure is even doing the adding; the front-end/UI is a Windows desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have not put together a proof of concept, but this might work.

You can configure an extended events session on databaseB that watches for all the procedures on databaseA that can insert into the table or any sql statements that run against the table on databaseA (using a LIKE '%your table name here%').
This is a custom solution that writes the XE session to a table: 
https://github.com/spaghettidba/XESmartTarget

You could probably mimic functionality by writing the XE events table to a custom user table every 1 minute or so using the SQL job agent.

Your session would monitor databaseA, write the XE output to databaseB, you write a trigger that upon each XE output write, it would compare the two tables and if there are differences, write the differences to your log table. This would be a nonstop running process, but it is still kind of a period scan in a way. The XE only writes when the event happens, but it is still running a check every couple of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you look at a data integration tool that can mine the transaction log for Change Data Capture events.  We are recently using StreamSets Data Collector for Oracle CDC but it also has SQL Server CDC.  There are many other competing technologies including Oracle GoldenGate and Informatica PowerExchange (not PowerCenter).  We like StreamSets because it is open source and is designed to build realtime data pipelines between DB at the schema level.  Till now we have used batch ETL tools like Informatica PowerCenter and Pentaho Data Integration.  I can near real-time copy all the tables in a schema in one StreamSets pipeline provided I already deployed DDL in the target. I use this approach between Oracle and Vertica. You can add additional columns to the target and populate them as part of the pipeline.

The only catch might be identifying which user made the change.  I don't know whether that is in the SQL Server transaction log. Seems probable but I am not a SQL Server DBA.

Comment: My reading of the doco on this indicate that changes are made to the database by at least one of the SP calls required to set this up, eg sys.sp_cdc_enable_db, sys.sp_cdc_enable_table.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at both solutions provided by the time of writing this answer (refer Dan Flippo and dfundaka) but found that the first - using *Change Data Capture* - required modification to the database and the second - using *Extended Events* - wasn't really a complete answer, though it got me thinking of other options.

And the option that seems cleanest, and doesn't require any database modification - is to use [SQL Server Dynamic Management Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/system-dynamic-management-views). Within this library residing, in the System database, are various procedures to view server process history - in this case INSERTs and UPDATEs - such as *sys.dm_exec_sql_text* and *sys.dm_exec_query_stats* which contain records of database transactions (and are, in fact, what *Extended Events* seems to be based on).

Though it's quite an involved process initially to extract the required information, the queries can be tuned and generalized to a degree.

There are restrictions on transaction history retention, etc but for the purposes of this particular exercise, this wasn't an issue.

I'm not going to select this answer as the correct one yet partly because it's a matter of preference as to how you approach the problem and also because I'm yet to provide a complete solution. Hopefully, I'll post back with that later. But if anyone cares to comment on this approach - good or bad - I'd be interested in your views.